# Allowed Host Setting for Django on EC2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, web-deployment, cloud-hosting, bitnami

I just deployed to an Amazon EC2 bitnami djnago stack and I'm having trouble with the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting in the settings.py file.  I am not sure what hostname to use or where to find it.  I have tried internal IP, external IP, localhost, domain name.  The only thing that gets the 500 error pages to stop, is:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

But, this is a security issue.  What am I missing?

Comment: Set it to `['.yourdomain.com']`. Where `yourdomain.com` is the domain name you're using to access it.

Comment: that did it! thanks.  i had tried ['www.domain.com'] before and that didn't work.  Why does the www screw it up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set it to -

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
  '.yourdomain.com'
]
```

Where `yourdomain.com` is the domain name you're using to access it.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) says -

> Values in this list can be fully qualified names (e.g.
>   'www.example.com'), in which case they will be matched against the
>   request’s Host header exactly (case-insensitive, not including port).
>   A value beginning with a period can be used as a subdomain wildcard:
>   '.example.com' will match example.com, www.example.com, and any other
>   subdomain of example.com.

When you set it to `www.yourdomain.com`, there must have been some request to another subdomain, other than `www`. Which caused the trouble. I cannot say exactly because I don't have that much information.