# django's ALLOWED_HOSTS throws error 500?

Tags: python, django, nginx

In my Django project's `settings.py` for deployment i want `mywebsite.com` to be the allowed hosts but putting it so throws the 500 error.

For production server when i use:

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'mywebsite.com']`
It throws error 500 on every page.

But if i change it to

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`
It works fine.

I checked `error.log` of nginx but there is not error logged.

But i guess its not safe to keep `*` and i just want to keep `mywebsite.com` or `www.mywebsite.com`

Please suggest why its throwing 500 error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably a duplicate of [Allowed Host Setting for Django on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466761/allowed-host-setting-for-django-on-ec2) where I can find the answer working fine (as they have accepted it). Please try it like and check if this works.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mywebsite.com']
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it still throws error 500. Is there any way to resolve it?